# Submitting an XML post request using Java

Tags: java, xml, post, http-post

I am trying to integrate a Usurv survey to my website.  To do this, I need to submit an XML request to the URL http://app.usurv.com/API/Gateway.svc/getcampaignforframe, using HTTP POST.  Then the response should contain a unique URL pointing to a survey.

Unfortunately I can't get it to work - the code compiles correctly but when I load the webpage I get the following exception:

```
"WARNING: URL = http://app.usurv.com/API/Gateway.svc/getcampaignforframe
 [Fatal Error] CampaignFrameRequest%3E:6:3: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>"."
```

I'm really confused about that as the XML doesn't even have a link 
tag, so I'm not sure where the error could be coming from. Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this and how I can fix it?

Here is the Java code:

```
public class UsurvSurveyElement extends RenderController 
{
  private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(UsurvSurveyElement.class.getName());
  String xml = "<CampaignFrameRequest xmlns='http://Qsurv/api' xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'><PartnerId>236</PartnerId><PartnerWebsiteID>45</PartnerWebsiteID><RespondentID>1</RespondentID><RedirectUrlComplete>http://localhost:8080/eveningstar/home</RedirectUrlComplete><RedirectUrlSkip>http://localhost:8080/eveningstar/home</RedirectUrlSkip></CampaignFrameRequest>";
  String strURL = "http://app.usurv.com/API/Gateway.svc/getcampaignforframe";

  @Override
  public void populateModelBeforeCacheKey(RenderRequest renderRequest, TopModel topModel, ControllerContext controllerContext ) 
  {
    super.populateModelBeforeCacheKey( renderRequest, topModel, controllerContext );  

    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(strURL);

    try 
    { 
        // Specify content type and encoding
        // If content encoding is not explicitly specified
        // ISO-8859-1 is assumed
        post.setRequestHeader(
            "Content-type", "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"); 
        LOG.warning("request headers: " +post.getRequestHeader("Content-type"));

        StringRequestEntity requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(xml);
        post.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);
        LOG.warning("request entity: " +post.getRequestEntity());

        String response = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
        LOG.warning("XML string = " +  xml); 
        LOG.warning("URL = " +  strURL); 
        topModel.getLocal().setAttribute("thexmlresponse",response);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   
        LOG.warning("Errors while executing postMethod "+ e);
    }  

    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = docBuilder.parse(strURL+xml);
        processNode(document.getDocumentElement());
        LOG.warning("doc output = " + document);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   
        LOG.warning("Errors while parsing XML: "+ e);
    }
} 

private void processNode(Node node) {
    // do something with the current node instead of System.out
    LOG.warning(node.getNodeName());

    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
        if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            //calls this method for all the children which is Element
            LOG.warning("current node: " + currentNode);
            processNode(currentNode);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line looks really strange, don't you mean to parse the response body instead?

```
Document document = docBuilder.parse(strURL+xml);
```

The parse method with a string parameter uses this string as an URL, so the XML parser is connection to the server again, using a GET request. The server is probably responding with an error message in HTML format, leading to the exception complaining about the `link` element.

Something like the following should work better:

```
Document document = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response)));
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  Unfortunately I'm now getting a null pointer exception.  The response variable is null and I'm not sure why it's not picking up the server response (which should be a URL).